# Remap RXJS observable to a timer start, without stream interruption

Tags: rxjs

What is the correct way in RXJS to remap an observable into a timer start value, without interrupting the original stream?

```js
obs.pipe(take(1000), startTimer())
   .subscribe(start => {
       // show how long it took to finish streaming 1000 values:
       const duration = Date.now() - start;
       console.log(duration); 
   });
```

I want `startTimer` to remap into once-off subscription with `start`, but without interrupting the original stream, i.e. in this case `subscribe` is to be triggered only after all 1000 values have finished streaming.

How do I implement such `startTimer`? It's supposed to result into a once-off `Date.now()` value to help measure full stream duration.

Or is there maybe a standard solution for this already that I'm missing?

### update-1

The expected result is like the one below, but without the need for creating `start` as an external variable, and instead make it part of the stream:

```js
const start = Date.now();

obs.pipe(take(1000))
    .subscribe({
        complete() {
            const duration = Date.now() - start;
            console.log(duration);
        }
    });
```

The reason I want to make it part of a stream is because the original observable and subscribers are very much detached from each other, as in sitting in unrelated source files.

P.S. Alternatively, a solution that emits `duration` in the end would also be good, if that is at all possible.

### update-2

In the end, I used a generic `drain` operand, designed to drain an observable stream, and then produce an observable at the end:

```js
/**
 * Drains the source observable till it completes, and then posts a new value-observable.
 */
function drain<T>(value: T | Observable<T> | (() => T | Observable<T>)) {
    const v = () => {
        const a = typeof value === 'function' ? value.call(null) : value;
        return a instanceof Observable ? a : of(a);
    }
    return s => defer(() => s.pipe(filter(_ => false), c => concat(c, v()))) as Observable<T>;
}
```

Using this operand, I can rewrite `startTimer` like this:

```js
const startTimer = () => drain(Date.now);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code that does what you describe pretty much exactly the way you describe it:

```ts
function logRunTime<T>(prefix: string): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return s => defer(() => {
    const start = Date.now();
    return s.pipe(
      tap({
        complete: () => console.log(`${prefix}: ${Date.now() - start}ms`)
      })
    );
  });
}

interval(1000).pipe(
  take(10),
  logRunTime("Ten Seconds of Interval")
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Output:

```html
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Ten Seconds of Interval: 10014ms
```

### Update 1

> do not make the original observable stop emitting values [...] we just do not want the source values

It seem to me that either you keep emitting the values or you don't.

Here is a version that drops the source emissions.
Is this what you're after?

```ts
function reduceRunTime<T>(prefix: string): OperatorFunction<T, string> {
  return s => defer(() => {
    const start = Date.now();
    return s.pipe(
      filter(_ => false),
      c => concat(c, of(null)),
      map(_ => `${prefix}: ${Date.now() - start}ms`)
    );
  }) as Observable<string>;
}

interval(1000).pipe(
  take(10),
  reduceRunTime("Ten Seconds of Interval")
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Output:

```html
Ten Seconds of Interval: 10013ms
```

### Update 2

If you don't want a string, this will emit the start time once the observable completes.

```ts
function startTimer() {
    return s => s.pipe(
        filter(_ => false),
        c => concat(c, of(Date.now()))
    ) as Observable<number>;
}
```

### Update 3

#### Two separate behaviours

I think update 2 may have been cleaned up too much. Consider this example:

```ts
const timed$ = interval(500).pipe(
  take(5),
  startTimer()
);

const logDiff = (start: number) => console.log(Date.now() - start);

timed$.subscribe(logDiff);

setTimeout(() => {
  timed$.subscribe(logDiff);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {
  timed$.subscribe(logDiff);
}, 5000);
```

The output:

```html
2521
3507
7511
```

Notably, because Observables are lazy (do nothing until subscribed), but `Date.now` is called when the observable is created. Your startTime may well be set long before the observable even starts. Making a 2.5s observable appear to require 7.5s.

Using defer fixes this problem as it doesn't create the observable until it is subscribed.

Updated `startTimer`

```ts
function startTimer() {
  return s => defer(() => s.pipe(
      filter(_ => false),
      c => concat(c, of(Date.now()))
  )) as Observable<number>;
}
```

New output for example above:

```html
2521
2507
2511
```

Now you can do fun things like run the same observable 10 times and average out the runtime to get a better idea of how long it will take.

```ts
const average = arr => arr.reduce( ( p, c ) => p + c, 0 ) / arr.length;

concat(...Array.from(Array(10)).map(_ => timed$)).pipe(
  map(start => Date.now() - start),
  tap(console.log),
  toArray()
).subscribe(runs => console.log("Average Runtime: ", average(runs)));
```

Output:

```html
2515
2506
2506
2506
2507
2505
2506
2506
2507
2507
Average Runtime: 2507.1
```

Comment: This code emits all original stream values, but I want just the timer start value, after the original stream has finished. Granted, a `duration` value instead would also be good.

Comment: What do you mean by "without interrupting the original stream" then?

Comment: `without interrupting the original stream` = do not make the original observable stop emitting values, because we want our `subscribe` when all values have been emitted, we just do not want the source values in our case, we only want either `start` or `duration`.

Comment: It sounds like you want the source unaltered and also altered at the same time. If the source doesn't stop emitting values, you'll keep getting those values. I've made a version that keep emitting them and just updated with one that filters out all emissions. Maybe you'll have to re-word what you mean?

Comment: Your updated version does produce the expected result, apart from being a string, while I just want the value of `start`. However, it does a lot extra, by using `filter`, `concat` and `map`, which will likely affect the duration measurement. I was hoping for somewhat a cleaner solution, if possible.

Comment: Based on your updated version, I created a [cleaned-up version of it](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-t/4cd75c08640129ae736cb487b22f16a3). That's basically what I was looking for, if you want to update your answer ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t - I think there's a bug in the cleaned up version that just emits the start time. I've demonstrated what I mean in another update above. It's an easy fix.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated both the [gist](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-t/4cd75c08640129ae736cb487b22f16a3) and my own question update to reflect this. Does this look ok to you?

Comment: @vitaly-t I don't see any problems :)